# In which cisco router or IOS verson i can use section command like "show run | section eigrp"

Tags: cisco, ios

I have seen videos in CBT nuggets for ccnp and ccna.
The instructor always uses `show run | section eigrp` and it looks very good command

But i am trying that in GNS , it says command not found

How can i use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the "selection" filter fetures was added to the show command in IOS 12.3(2)

[Show Command Section Filter](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_3t/12_3t2/feature/guide/gtshfltr.html)

There are some other useful filters which may work as an alternative sh run | ?

Comment: i am using gns which has 12.2 ios , how can i upgrade it

Comment: You need a valid Cisco SmartNET contract to download a newer version of router IOS.

Comment: @Mirror51 See http://serverfault.com/questions/286620/how-to-obtain-cisco-ios-firmware

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using

**show run | begin router eigrp**

As far as I know that is the command to view the running config lines relating to eigrp configuration. That should pretty much work on all IOS'es.